# How to inject page scipt to main document and execute it as first script using chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, synchronization

I'm working on chrome-extension, I need to inject page script to main document. The script has to be executed as first script. 
In FF extension there is an option to change response body, so I'm looking for responses with html documents and I change the response from `<html><head>...` to `<html><script src='pagescript'></script><head>...`

Looks like in chrome-extension I'm not able to change response body so I'm trying different approach.
In `manifest.json` I defined content script that should be executed on `document_start`. Also I added my `pagescript.js` to `web_accessible_resources`

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "pageScript.js"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": [
      "src/add-page-scripts.js"
    ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }]
```

In `content-script` I tried different ways to inject my `page script` to document

1)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("pageScript.js");
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

In this case `PageScript.js` is the first `element` in `html`, but it's executed asynchronously, so when it's executed, other html elements may already exists or even other scripts may be executed

2)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "alert('Page script')";
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

In this case cript is executed as first script, so this is nearly what I need. But I would have to have `pagescript.js` content instead of url

3) I tried to extend #2 and inject script that will inject my `pagescript` using `document.write`.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "document.write(\"<script>alert('Page script')<\"+ \"/script>\")";
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

But once I use `document.write`, the original page is not loaded at all. Looks like `document.write` breaks page loading. It's weird because my script is first script on the page, `document.readyState` returns `loading`, so I guess `document.write` should be safe (but it's not)

Questions are:

- why `document.write` breaks page?
- is there other way to inject page script to document and make sure it's executed as first script in document (even before other `html elements` are created?

Comment: The simplest method is to inject the script code either as a literal string or a function converted to IIFE string as shown in [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)